# Opencart - Change header for product page only

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3

Can I initialize some variable in product controller `product.php`, then load it to header controller `header.php` and use it in view `header.twig`, to load certain information based on this variable? If not, how can I determine whether the page with the product is open or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way determine product page in header.php

```
if (isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
    $product_id = (int)$this->request->get['product_id'];

} else {
    $product_id = 0;
}

if ($product_id) {
//... some code for product page
}
```

Also you can combine check with product controller route in header.php

```
if (isset($this->request->get['route']) && $this->request->get['route'] == 'product/product' && isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
// some code for product page
}
```